# Worklight: custom user ID for Push NOTIFICATION_USER table

Tags: push-notification, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, userid

I want to know, Is there a way to save a **custom UserID in NOTIFICATION_USER** in place of log-in user ID?

For example, currently it is saving UserID  as "aahad" in the NOTIFICATION_USER and I want it to save "12345" in UserID.

Answer (score 0):

You should not manually edit database Worklight server uses. In case you want to add some custom properties to user subscription do it using userSubscription object. See following APIs:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_method_wl_server_getusernotifi.html
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_method_usersubscription_save.html

Note, that you can also update user subscription in onSubscribe callback of your event source:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_method_wl_server_createeventso.html

Comment: Thanks for it. The **userSubscription** works after subscription. But i was thinking to handle it at the time of subscription, so that WL can  save another value for userid field in the notification table. thanks